# Python, Math, and Latex: Display + Compute?

Tags: python, latex, jupyter-notebook

Suppose that I have a family of equations that depend on a variable n. What I want to do is to write a simple code so that by just by choosing a particular n, it will generate the equation for that particular value of n.

Here is an example of a code I wrote on ipython. It will display the partial sum of the harmonic series for any n of my choosing (without evaluating it).

```
from IPython.display import display, Math, Latex

txt = "$1"
n = 100000
long = 0
for i in range(n):
    if (i<3 or i > n -3):
        str = "+\dfrac{{1}}"
        temp = "{0}".format(i+2)
        str +="{"+temp+"}"
        txt+=str
    else:
        if long == 0:
            txt +="+..."
            long+=1
    txt +="$"
display(Math(txt))
```

This generates the following output:

[image]

And of course, I can adjust my n to whatever value I want.

The way this code is written, it doesn't really adapt too well to other types of expressions.  And I would also like to have " = ::whatever the value is to my desired precision::"

Is there a smart way to do this either on ipython or latex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing particularly difficult about producing LaTeX equations from Python. Only the the fact that you have to escape things like `\` in strings and `{}` in `str.format` make it somewhat tedious.

You can use a list comprehension, list concatenation and the `join` method for strings to reduce your example to three lines of code.

```
In [1]: tmp = ['\dfrac{{1}}{{{:.1f}}}'.format(float(n)) for n in range(2, 12)]

In [2]: sl = ['$s'] + tmp[:3] + ['...'] + tmp[-3:]

In [3]: sl
Out[3]: 
['$s',
 '\\dfrac{1}{2.0}',
 '\\dfrac{1}{3.0}',
 '\\dfrac{1}{4.0}',
 '...',
 '\\dfrac{1}{9.0}',
 '\\dfrac{1}{10.0}',
 '\\dfrac{1}{11.0}']

In [4]: ' + '.join(sl) + '$'
Out[4]: '$s + \\dfrac{1}{2.0} + \\dfrac{1}{3.0} + \\dfrac{1}{4.0} + ... + \\dfrac{1}{9.0} + \\dfrac{1}{10.0} + \\dfrac{1}{11.0}$'
```

To calculate the results of expressions and format them, I've written a module called [TeXcalc](http://rsmith.home.xs4all.nl/software/texcalc.html). Starting from Python expressions it uses `eval` to calculate their results and the `ast` module to format them as LaTeX. Keep in mind that the usage of `eval` makes it unsuitable for use with untrusted input.

**Update**:

Using string formatting for +/- can be done like this;

```
In [1]: '{:+d}'.format(1)
Out[1]: '+1'

In [2]: '{:+d}'.format(-1)
Out[2]: '-1'
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if it would be possible to use the "join" command to do an alternating series?

Comment: @Braindead In that case you need to use a space as the joining character and make the sign part of the list generated by the list comprehension. One method to make alternating signs is to multiply by `(-1)**n`.

Comment: That wouldn't really work, since "+" sign will not be generated by (-1)**n, right?  I ended up using something like ["+","-"](n%2) instead, and importing float division so that I can just have my "1/2" rather than "1/2.0"

Comment: @Braindead You can use string formatting to add +/-. See updated answer.